# Tries for sorting strings in linear time?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to sort strings alphabetically in linear time and thought about using tries for this, my question is What's the time complexity of running a Pre-Order transversal on tries? is it **O(n)** ?

Comment: If sting length is bounded, you could use radix sort.

Comment: what do you mean by bounded? The strings are variable in size

Comment: More specifically, if you have `N` strings and the maximum string length is `O(1)`.

Comment: @abeer00: if there is no "upper bound" of the length of the string, you can not sort this in less than *O(n log n)*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the question statement is as follows: Given a sequence of `n` English words of length `k`, implement an algorithm that sorts them alphabetically in `Θ(n)`.  Let `k` and `n` be flexible, i.e., automatically determined when reading the input sequence

Comment: In a hypothetical scenario where `k = n^2` this should not be possible.

Comment: I think the question needs more details. Obviously in general sorting is not possible in linear time, so there must be something the question is not mentioning. For example bounded length, or perhaps `n` means the number of bytes of input.

Comment: If you think of a string as a number expressed in base 256, then I think both a trie and a radix sort will be O(nlogn).  You're likely better off with Timsort - that is, unless your base 256 numbers are in a pretty compressed space.  Both Python and Java use Timsort out of the box now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be a little careful with the way you measure complexity in this case.  A lot of times, people pretend that sorting **N** strings with a comparison-based sort takes **O(N log N)** time, but that is not really true in the worst case unless the length of the strings is bounded.  It is the *expected* time if the strings are randomized, however, so it's not a bad approximation for many use cases.

If you want to account for possible long strings with long common prefixes, then you *change the meaning* of **N** to refer to the total size of the input, including all the strings.  With this new definition, you can sort a list of strings in **O(N)** time.

Inserting the strings into a trie, or better a radix tree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) and then doing a preorder traversal is one way, and yes that works in **O(N)** time, where **N** is the total size of the input.

But it's faster and easier to do a radix sort: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort  The Most-Significant-Digit-First variant works best with variable-length inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Radix Sort can be applied in this case to sort them in `O(n)` refer to the following code implemented in c++:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class RadixSort {
    public:

        static char charAt(string s,int n){
            return s[n];
        }

        static void countingSort(string arr[],int n,int index,char lower,char upper){
            int countArray[(upper-lower)+2];
            string tempArray[n];

            for(int i =0; i < sizeof(countArray)/sizeof(countArray[0]); i++)
                countArray[i]=0;

            //increase count for char at index
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                int charIndex = (arr[i].length()-1 < index) ? 0 : (charAt(arr[i],index) - lower+1);
                countArray[charIndex]++;
            }

            //sum up countArray;countArray will hold last index for the char at each strings index
            for(int i=1;i<sizeof(countArray)/sizeof(countArray[0]);i++){
                countArray[i] += countArray[i-1];
            }

            for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
                int charIndex = (arr[i].length()-1 < index) ? 0 : (charAt(arr[i],index) - lower+1);
                tempArray[countArray[charIndex]-1] = arr[i];
                countArray[charIndex]--;
            }

            for(int i=0;i<sizeof(tempArray)/sizeof(tempArray[0]);i++){
                arr[i] = tempArray[i];   
            }
        }

        static void radixSort(string arr[],int n,char lower,char upper){
            int maxIndex = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                if(arr[i].length()-1 > maxIndex){
                maxIndex = arr[i].length()-1;
                }
            }

            for(int i=maxIndex;i>=0;i--){
                countingSort(arr,n,i,lower,upper);
            }
        }
};


int main(){

    string arr[] = {"a", "aa", "aaa","kinga", "bishoy","computer","az"};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    RadixSort::radixSort(arr,n,'a','z');
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. it is not O(n). it is Omega(k(log(k))n).
without any other restriction,and this is the case as i understand from your question, it is just comparison based sorting algorithm.
Sorting an array of length k is in Omega(klog(k)),
and doing it n times, without any connections between the times, will lead to
Omega(klog(k)n).
You can read more here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lower-bound-on-comparison-based-sorting-algorithms/

If you look at k as bounded, because there is no ***ENGLISH*** word longer then 10^1000000 (Which probably larger than atoms on Earth), then sort an array of bounded length is in O(1), and doing it n time will lead to O(n).

You get a lot from dealing with infinity, but sometimes you have to pay back...